# How do I keep a mouse cursor from changing to 'selected text' in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have two CSS classes, one applies to a `<div>` (class: `divBack`), and one to a `<pre>` tag (class: `preFooter`):

```
#divBack{
position:absolute;
left:0px;
top:0px;
z-index:10;
width:100%;
height:100%;
overflow:visible;
cursor:pointer;}

#preFooter{
position:absolute;
top:100%;
height:70px;
margin-top:-70px;
width:100%;
z-index:20;
cursor:pointer;}
```

I'd like to use JQuery for a drag and drop on the `div`, but when I try to `mousedown` on the `div`, the cursor changes to the same style as when text is selected.  How do I keep the mouse cursor from changing to the 'selected text' cursor during this operation?  I tried using cursor changes in CSS but it didn't work when there's a `mousedown` on the div.

Comment: Can you show us your JQuery code?

Comment: I didnot use jquery for now,I used .onmousedown to emuluate it.

Comment: @namiheike Then show us that code? Give us something more than just the CSS, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CSS3 you can set the options:
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;

that disabled selection and cursor manipulation from browser

and in CSS3 you can look to events

```
dragstart
drag
dragenter
dragleave
dragover
drop
dragend
```

not mousedown

Answer (score 2):

It seems that it only occurs on webkit, and just set `-webkit-user-select: none;` to the pre can solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is the text in the div inside another element, like a `<p>` for example?

If so, try adding the `cursor:pointer` style to the child element as well

Comment: no,there are just these two elements in the page,and some text in the < pre >

Comment: try adding !important to the cursor:pointer style rule. Generally frowned upon, but if it solves this specific problem...